# How to change file colors in Ubuntu?

Tags: nautilus, files, colors

I am trying to organize my computer's file management system, for this purpose. How can I change the file colors in Ubuntu to distinguish each of them easier?

Comment: what file manger are you using . each file manager has different methods of achieving these .

Comment: Hi Smit, I use the default file manager of ubuntu 16.04